# alias url with sinatra / padrino

Tags: routes, sinatra, padrino

I've this and it works

```
  get :about, :map => '/about_us' do
    render :erb, "<%= 'foo' %>"
  end
  get '/:slug' do
    redirect "/about_us" # <--
  end
```

Is possible to do in some way "render" instead of "redirect"?
or something like render 'posts/1'

Answer (score 3):

```
get :about, :map => '/about_us' do
  render :erb, "<%= 'foo' %>"
end

get '/:slug' do
  call env.merge('PATH_INFO' => '/about_us')
end
```